# Проблема с масссивом в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Я создал функцию, принимающую массив и возвращающую на выходе сумму его элементов. Вместо суммы она возвращает undefined. Почему это так и как это исправить?

```js
let arr = [1, 7, 98, 65, 888, 45] 
let sum

const sumElements = (arr) => {
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
        sum = arr[i] += arr[i++]
    }
}

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Так потому что нет никакого вызова `sumElements(arr)` + цикл работать не будет, так как Вы спутали буквы в `arr.lenght` должно быть `arr.length`

Comment: `console.log( [1, 7, 98, 65, 888, 45].reduce((total, amount) => total + amount) )` можно проще..

Comment: @Jour да, Ваш пример и считает верно, кстати, потому что если использовать код из вопроса, то будет 1776 из-за выражения `arr[i] += arr[i++]`.

Comment: @Jour для новичков это явно не проще)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский боюсь это не новичок, а очередной бот, задавший вопрос и который тут больше не появится) не вижу смысла таким что-то разжевывать, поэтому просто дал решение, на случай если человек живой и заглянет сюда еще раз :)

Comment: @Jour тогда прозе вообще ничего не писать, чтобы не тратить своё время и силы  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не потратил на автора более минуты, сильно не пострадал)) прошу заметить, ваш ответ не отмечен как принятый... я уверен на 90% что автор сюда больше не зайдет, а для остальных пользы в топике вообще нет) такие вопросы стоит просто удалять

Answer (score 1):

Строка `let sum` говорит о том, что `sum` инициализируется со значением `undefined`. Понятное дело, сложить `undefined` с числами ничего не даст. Значит надо переменную инициализировать числом. Нулём, если быть точным

---

и должно быть видимо `sum += arr[i];`

---

и ещё, не `lenght`, а `length`